# Trying to connect to WiFi on ESP32 using credentials from SD card

Tags: esp32

I am trying to connect to WiFi on an ESP32 using credentials I stored on an SD card. I am able to read and parse the credential and printing them to the serial monitor shows that the SSID and password are correct, but it is not connecting to WiFi. When I hardcode the WiFi credentials it works. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: write a sketch that gets the SSID and password from the SD card and compares them to hardcoded values ... that will tell you if they are the same ... also, print out the length of each of them

Comment: It would really help if you showed the code you are using.

Comment: thanks i was able to figure it out i had to find a way to convert the string to a const char* this way:  WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), pass.c_str());

Answer (score 0):

I use the NVS partition to store NON VOLATILE information.

I use this library: [NVS library](https://github.com/rpolitex/ArduinoNvs)

You can save like string and restore after reset/off.

Example:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "ArduinoNvs.h"

void setup() {   
    NVS.begin();
    Serial.begin(115200);
    // write to flash
    String set_SSID = "WIFI_name"; 
    NVS.setString("nvs_wifi_name", set_SSID ); //upload 1 time. after comment this line and upload again **
    // read from flash
    String get_SSID = NVS.getString("nvs_wifi_name");
    Serial.printf("Wifi name stored %s\n", get_SSID);
}


void loop() {}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.